# iphone to ipad, iphone 4 uialertview problems

Tags: iphone, ipad, rendering, uialertview

So I've upgraded the code to the ipad (i.e. converted to a universal app). However, the UIAlertview rendering seems to be off for IOS4. Instead of being positioned in the middle, it jumps up and is displayed on top, with half the box cut off. Same goes for landscape orientation.

It is my understanding that the UIalertview is always set in the middle? I looked through the code and I did not set up the frame/position anywhere in the code. This only happens for 4.0, on both the iphone 4 and the itouch running 4.0. Every other version is fine, including the ipad. Any thoughts?

Thanks.

Comment: what does your create look like? do you have a title and content or just one or the other? i saw this same thing and ended up having to adjust the frame anyway so did you try moving the frame?

Comment: I'm actually debugging this for someone else. By create, do you mean the allocation and initialization? I think it has both a title and content. I looked at the initialization and didn't see any frame use. I'll check again.

By curiosity, does this show on only 4.0 and not the other versions for you, and only after upgrading to universal?

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be a bug. I also had the Problem on iPad with iOS 3.2.

Solution:

a) Check your app state: 
In iOS 4 just use

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationState
```

Older iOS: Store your app state manually:

```
-(void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    self.appIsInBackground = YES;
}

-(void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{
    self.appIsInBackground = YES;
}

-(void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Open your UIAlert here if self.appIsInBackground == YES;

    self.appIsInBackground = NO;
}
```

b) open the UIAlert after the app did become active, as shown above in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Does your alert have any Textfields added ?

Because in 4.0+ iOS scrolls the alertview to visible part if you have a textfield in the alertview.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem for iPad 3.2 when application resign active and in that time alert is shown that alert will be shown on top left corner. So i fixed using following code in the method -(void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application

```
//Check that key window is alert view
if ([[[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow description] hasPrefix:@"<_UIAlertOverlayWindow"]) {
    //Yes then check for subviews tht are alertViews
    UIWindow *alertViewWindow = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;
    NSArray *subViews = [alertViewWindow subviews];
    for (UIView *subview in subViews) 
    {
        if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UIAlertView class]]) 
        {
            //Retain it
            UIAlertView *alertView = (UIAlertView *)[subview retain];
            //Now dismiss it and then show it again
            [alertView dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:NO];//Here ClickedButtonIndex must be according to cancel button
            //Show the alert view again
            [alertView show];
            //Release previsous retained object
            [alertView release];

        }
    }
}
```